# TClientDataSet error executing with TParam of blob type (ftBlob)

Tags: delphi, blob, parameters, tclientdataset

We are using MSSQL 2012.

Trying to update Client photo with Stored Procedure

```
spui_SetClientPhoto
int ClientID
VarBinary(Max) Photo
```

Program runs fine with pure ADO:

```
ADO.ProcedureName:='spui_SetClientPhoto';
ADO.Parameters.CreateParameter('@ClientsID',ftInteger,pdInput,0,95075);
ADO.Parameters.CreateParameter('@Photo',ftBlob,pdInput,0,NULL);
ADO.Parameters[1].LoadFromFile('C:\Photo.png',ftBlob);
ADO.ExecProc;
```

But with CDS it cause an error:

Implicit Conversion from datatype Varchar(max) to Varbinary(max) is not allowed.

```
 ADO.ProcedureName:='spui_SetClientPhoto';
 cds.SetProvider(ADO);
 cds.Params.CreateParam(ftInteger,'@ClientsID',ptInput).AsInteger:=95075;
 cds.Params.CreateParam(ftBlob,'@Photo',ptInput).LoadFromFile('C:\Photo.png', ftBlob);
 cds.Execute;
```

e.g. cannot run CDS with Parameters of BLOB type. Any solution for this?

Comment: Could you add the DDL of the strored proc?  It's pointless readers seeing if they can reproduce the problem without that.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me, with the Picture field type in the AdoQuery and
CDS set to ftGraphic, and the Stored Proc's DDL set to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetClientPhoto](@ClientID int, @Picture Image)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    update table_2 
      set picture = @Picture
    where
      ID = @ClientID
END
```

Code

```
procedure TForm1.SavePictureViaStoredProc;
var
  PrvCommandText,
  PrvSql : String;
  ID : Integer;
const
  scTestImage = 'D:\TestPictures\TestBMP.BMP';
begin
  //  First, save the text of the AdoQuery's Sql and the CDS's CommandText
  PrvCommandText := CDS1.CommandText;
  PrvSql := AdoQuery1.SQL.Text;

  //  Save the iD of the row we want to use
  ID := CDS1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
  try
    //  Allow CommandText changes on the DSP
    DataSetProvider1.Options := DataSetProvider1.Options + [poAllowCommandText];
    CDS1.Close;

    // construct a Sql statement to invoke the Stored Proc
    CDS1.CommandText := 'exec dbo.SetClientPhoto @ClientID = :' + IntToStr(ID) + ',  @Picture = :Picture';

    // Set up parameters
    CDS1.Params.Clear;
    CDS1.Params.CreateParam(ftInteger, '@ClientID', ptInput);
    CDS1.Params.CreateParam(ftGraphic, '@Picture', ptInput);
    CDS1.Params.ParamByName('@ClientID').Value := ID;
    CDS1.Params.ParamByName('@Picture').LoadFromFile(scTestImage, ftGraphic);

    AdoQuery1.Close;
    AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := '';
    CDS1.Execute;  // This executes the stored proc
    CDS1.Params.Clear;
  finally
    ADoQuery1.SQL.Text := PrvSql;
    CDS1.CommandText := PrvCommandText;
    CDS1.Open;
  end;

end;
```

Note:  I very rarely store images in databases, and have not yet managed to get this to work with .Jpg and .Png files.  I vaguely recall that there is an extra step needed with storing those in a DB without getting a "Stream read error" or "Invalid image" exception, and I'll see if I can remind myself of it later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But you are executing this as simple SQL Query, not as Stored Proc. Our solution is to encode binary as Base64,send to server encode it back to binary and save

Comment: "But you are executing this as simple SQL Query, not as Stored Proc"  Not sure what you mean - the whole point of what I do in that code is to set the CommandText of the CDS to invoke the stored proc on the server via the AdoQuery.  If you want something different, you had better make it a whole lot clearer in your q exactly want you **do** want.